# AS3 Removing Object from Stage

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

Title is quite vague, sorry about that. Can't think of how to ask this question in one sentence.

I will summarize what my code should do:

1. Prompts user for a number between 1-99. This number is the number of mines that will appear on stage.
2. Once the mines appear on stage, the user can click any mine and an 'explosion' will occur.
3. The mine that just exploded will be removed from stage.
4. Then, the 'explosion' will set off the nearest two.
5. Those two mines will be removed from stage while two more mines are set off. (ie chain reaction)

I have steps 1-3. I am having trouble 'setting off' the nearest two mines (ie removing from stage).

I made it possible to determine the two closest mines from the last exploded one, but I can't seem to find a way on how to remove them.

Code:

```
package 
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldType;
import flash.events.*;

public class Minefield extends MovieClip
{

    var inputNumber:int;
    var iField:TextField = new TextField();
    var button:iButton = new iButton();
    var i:int;
    var mines:Array = new Array();

    public function Minefield()
    {

        var explosion:iExplosion = new iExplosion();

        iField.type = "input";
        iField.height = 18;
        iField.x = 460;
        iField.y = 275;
        iField.border = true;
        iField.restrict = "0-9";
        iField.maxChars = 2;
        stage.focus = iField;
        addChild(iField);
        addChild(button);
        button.x = 450;
        button.y = 175;
        button.buttonMode = true;
        button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, UponClick);


    }

    function AddMines()
    {
        for (i = 0; i < inputNumber; i++)
        {
            CreatorOfMine();
            mines[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, UponMineClick)
            mines[i].buttonMode = true;
        }
    }

    function CreatorOfMine()
    {
        mines[i] = new Mine();
        MineLocation()
    }

    function MineLocation()
    {
        mines[i].x = Math.round(Math.random() * 925);
        mines[i].y = Math.round(Math.random() * 525);
        mines[i].rotation = Math.random() * 360;
        addChild(mines[i]);

    }

    function UponClick(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        inputNumber = int(iField.text);
        RemoverOfChildren();

    }

    function RemoverOfChildren()
    {
        removeChild(button);
        removeChild(iField);
        AddMines();
    }

    function UponMineClick(event:MouseEvent)
    {
        var mineObject:Mine = Mine(event.currentTarget)
        var expl:iExplosion = new iExplosion() 
        expl.x = mineObject.x
        expl.y = mineObject.y
        expl.rotation = mineObject.rotation
        addChild(expl)
        removeChild(mineObject)
        ChainReaction(mineObject)

    }

    function ChainReaction(mineObject:Mine)
    {
        Distances(mineObject,i)


    }


    function Distances(mineObject:Mine, i:int)
    {
        var DistanceArray:Array = new Array()
        var x1:Number = mineObject.x;
        var y1:Number = mineObject.y;
        for (var q:int = 0; q < (mines.length); q++){
            if (q != i){
                var x2:Number = mines[q].x
                var y2:Number = mines[q].y

                var dy:Number = y2 - y1 
                var dx:Number = x2 - x1

                var dist:Number = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(dx*dx + dy*dy))
                if (dist != 0)
                {   
                    DistanceArray[q] = [dist]
                    //trace(dist)
                    trace(DistanceArray[q])
                }
                else if (dist == 0)
                { 
                    continue
                }
            }
        }
        FindNearestMines(DistanceArray)
    }

    function FindNearestMines(DistanceArray:Array){

        DistanceArray.sort(Array.NUMERIC);
// Sorted my distances numerically so that I can figure out the closest two. How do I remove those two mines from the stage?


    }

}
}
```

Comment: You have the mines in an array. Can't you just use something like removeChild(mines[x])?

Comment: Uhm, but how? I don't know which mine is which. Basically, in one array I have the mines, but at random locations. In the other, I have the distances from one mine to all the other mines. Since I need to remove the closest two, I sorted the array numerically and with that I know that the first two need to be removed. removeChild(DistanceArray[0,1]) doesn't work, obviously, because nothing in that array is on stage.

Comment: Not sure that you can remove 2 children at the same time like that. Hve you tried removeChild[0] and removeChild[1]? ALso, I found before that you sometimes have to remove an object like this: object.parent.removeChild(object).

Comment: Also, you can try giving each mine an unique name, then removing them by name.

Comment: Also, you should not be using the index 'i' the way you are. It could easily confuse your app.

Comment: Hmm. First, you say "two more mines". Isn't it four, as one mine will set off two and the second will set off another two? Next, if a nearest mine has already exploded, will you check for another or not? And last, you say you're able to get smallest distance out of distances array, then your second index of the value found will be the index of the mine you need to remove.

Comment: You should not sort distances array, as you are then eradicating the info from out there. Instead, use the "find minimum" algorithm over distances array, store the index where's the minimum, and blow up the mine that corresponds to the index. Remember to strip (zero, maybe) the value found after you've searched through the array so that this mine won't be selected anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Okie, I took a closer look at your code, and here is my suggestion.

In your Distances function, you can do something like this:

Make 2 temporary arrays. One called mines_l and one called distances_l
Take the first mine, stick it in mines_l, and put its distance in distances_l.
Then iterrate through your mines. Each mine, compare with distances_l[0]. If it is closer than disances_l[0], move distances_l[0] and mines_l[0] to ...[1].
If the mine is closer than ...[1] but not closer than ...[0], then replace ...[1] with the new mine.

in the end, you will have the 2 closest mines in the array mines_l.

Also, you might consider changing the mines array into a property. As it stands now, you have no mechanism to remove mines from the array. If you turn it into a property, you can just collect the current mines into an array when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Generate an Array where each array item is an Object containing "mine", and "distance" fields. Then sort that array by distance using Array.sortOn("distance", Array.NUMERIC).

This example calculates the distances of a _target to an array of _movieClips, and returns a new Array of movieClip / distance objects sorted by distance.

```
function getClosestMovieClips(_target:MovieClip, _movieClips:Array, _num:int):Array{

    // This array will store our objects. 
    var tempArray:Array = [];

    // Loop through _movieclips
    for(var i:int = 0; i < _movieClips.length; i++){

        // Don't check _target's distance
        if (_target != _movieClips[i]){

            // Distance calculation
            var dy:Number = _movieClips[i].y - _target.y;
            var dx:Number = _movieClips[i].x - _target.x;

            var dist:Number = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(dx*dx + dy*dy));

            // New object contains mc and distance
            var tempObject:Object = {
                mc:_movieClips[i], 
                distance:dist
            }

            // Push object into tempArray
            tempArray.push( tempObject );
        }
    }

    // Sort tempArray based on distance field
    tempArray.sortOn("distance",Array.NUMERIC);

    // return new array with length of the parameter _num
    return tempArray.slice(0,_num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How is your code working with these functions:

```
function CreatorOfMine()
{
    mines[i] = new Mine();
    MineLocation()
}

function MineLocation()
{
    mines[i].x = Math.round(Math.random() * 925);
    mines[i].y = Math.round(Math.random() * 525);
    mines[i].rotation = Math.random() * 360;
    addChild(mines[i]);

}
```

It needs at least an integer parameter to acess the mines[] array :)

In AS3, we need to remove all the listeners of a DisplayObject before removing it from stage. If you just remove the object from the stage but leave all the listeners, it will not be removed.

So you need a small function like this:

```
    function removeMineFromStage(var i):void {
        mines[i].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK);
        //remove any other event listeners that you might have added.
        removeChild(mines[i]);
        mines[i] = null;
    }
```

Comment: Okay, but before that I need to know which mines to remove.

Comment: Why not creating a tile map for the mines in an array? Such as mines[x][y]. Then you will always remove something like:
mines[x-1][y-1]
mines[x-1][y]
mines[x][y-1]